# Angularjs2 http ajax call returning complete php code

Tags: php, ajax, http, angular

Am making http ajax call to local php file but it's echoing complete php code, am new to angularjs2. can someone help me please.

Here is my angularjs2 code.

```
makeHttpCall():Promise<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.sampleUrl, {headers : this.headers}).toPromise().then((response){
        console.log (response)
    }).catch(this.handleError);

}
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php
 $arr = array('name'=>'Dr.Nayana');
 echo json_encode($arr);?>
```

Here is my log
[image]

I need to get the object of that php array.

Am running the project using "npm start" command.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your server is not configured to handle php files properly. The request should return the processed php file, instead it is returned as a simple text file.

you should use a web server like apache with the php module correctly configured:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Comment: what server do you use ?

Comment: from the url you are using port 3000, I guess you are using express on node js ? if it is the case then there is no chance that you can run your php script, check the link to get indications on how to do

Comment: Where did you get the base code ? by the way you should not use comments for adding details to your question, please edit your question in order to have every information in it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code.

```
<?php
 $arr = array('name'=>'Dr.Nayana');
 echo json_decode($arr);?>
```

With below mentioned code.

```
<?php
 $arr = array('name'=>'Dr.Nayana');
 echo json_encode($arr);?>
```

> json_encode encode array in php